# Python - Should there be made an attempt to be consistent with the arg type in optional args?

Tags: python

My doubt is simple. Should I do an effort to be consistent with argument types when using optional arguments?

An example:

```
def example_method(str_arg_1=None):
    if str_arg_1 is not None:
        # do something
```

My `arg` is allways a `str`,except when it is not passed in the method call, so I'm not sure if is a good practice to use `None`in this case.

I came to this doubt because I don't know how to write my docstrings, is the `str_arg_1`consider `str` even if sometimes is `None`?

Comment: You could use  (str_arg_1 = '') and then test: if str_arg_1:

Comment: If str_arg_1 is None it will be of None type. Not str type.You may verify this with type(str_arg_1).

Comment: Looks like you're looking for [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)?

Comment: @lonewaft thank you, i wasn't aware that existed. Any way I'm not using python3.5 so I'm using docstrings for hints in the IDE

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge Which may be wrong or problematic because then you can't distinguish the case of a caller not giving the optional argument and giving explicitly the empty string as argument.

Comment: @BlackJack Yes, you're right about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Names don't have types; only the values they refer to have types. In this case, it is perfectly normal to document that `str_arg_1` will refer to a `str` object or `None`, with an explanation of what each means. As far as a docstring is concerned, it's safe to say everyone will understand what you mean if you state that an argument that *should* be a `str` may also take `None`.

---

In PEP-484, which deals with providing statically checkable type usage, this notion of using `None` is not just acceptable, but catered to.

If `str_arg_1` should *always* be a string, you would hint it as

```
def example_method(str_arg_1: str):
```

If it is allowed be `None` as well, you would indicate that with a *union* type

```
def example_method(str_arg_1: Union[str, None]):
```

As this is a very common case, there is a shortcut for indicating this:

```
def example_method(str_arg_1: Optional[str]):
```

In fact, if the default value is `None`, the static checker that uses these type annotations assumes the use of `Optional`, so the following are equivalent:

```
def example_method(str_arg_1: Optional[str] = None):
def example_method(str_arg_1: str = None):
```